# Configuring a default blank Apache VirtualHost on port 443 isn't working

Tags: apache-2.2, https, httpd, httpd.conf

I want to create a default blank page VirtualHost for my server so that anyone who attempts to browse directly to the IP address (e.g. `https://10.123.123.123/`) is shown a blank page.

I've done this for HTTP connections easily enough using a `_default_:80` VirtualHost like this:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
    ServerName nothing
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/blank
    ErrorLog logs/blank-error_log
    CustomLog logs/blank-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

However, if I try the above for HTTPS (replacing "80" with "443"), I get "connection interrupted" errors from browsers even for the legitimate VirtualHosts running on port 443 of the same server.

Is there a way I can create a blank/default host for HTTPS on port 443?

Comment: you need server certificates for SSL. certificates need a matching hostname or, in your case, the ip address as the name.

Comment: If you only replace the port number, and as @GeraldSchneider says, don't include an actual TLS certificate, you can can only connect over plain http to port 443, hence the *"connection interrupted"* error. Most likely plain **`http`** `://<your-ip>:443`  does work